# Css Grid Child item not centering

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying out a layout using CSS grid. Inside the header I have a div with a class called logo and I want it vertical aligned.

Here is the full code (View full-screen to see the issue):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "h h" "s m" "f f";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: red;
}

.header .logo {
  display: inline-grid;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  align-content: center;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: s;
  background-color: grey;
}

.main {
  grid-area: m;
  background-color: purple;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="main">Main Content</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I've tried: align-content: center and justify-self: center, but it's not moving from the top.

How can I vertical align class logo in the header using css grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
.header .logo {
  display: inline-grid;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; //remove this
  align-content: center;
  height: 100%; //This will work for responsive screens as well.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this what you want to do

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: grid;
      height: 100%;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-areas: "h h" "s m" "f f";
      grid-gap: 10px;
    }
    
    .header {
      padding: 70px 0;     /* this code */
      grid-area: h;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .header .logo {
      display: inline-grid;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      grid-area: s;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    .main {
      grid-area: m;
      background-color: purple;
    }
    
    .footer {
      grid-area: f;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="main">Main Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

> Other Opsion

```
 .header {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
    grid-area: h;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .header .logo {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I mean vertically centered. It should be on the left but in the vertical center on the header. You can only see the issue when you have it on full page. I've posted a screenshot

Comment: OK, i am waiting

Comment: Is this the image you want? I attached a screenshot.

Comment: Okay, now I understand, I'm updating the answer immediately.

Comment: Sorry, using px would not automatically stay centered if the header was to resize at runtime

Comment: you can use padding to center vertically

Comment: There is another method you can take a look at it too.I updated it and added it to the bottom.